# where "small mage width" defined in oscommerce 2.3.4

Tags: oscommerce

I want to know where SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT are defined in oscommerce !!!

```
tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $listing['products_image'], $listing['products_name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT)
```

Answer (score 2):

They are configuration values that you can set from the Administration Panel.  In the left column fine "Configuration".  In that box, you'll see a link for "Images".  There, you can edit the default image sizes for various image types.